# PHP how to count an array?

Tags: php

this is my code

```
foreach($ServerPlayers as $sValue)
{
    ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?= $sValue['playerid'] ?></th>
      <td><?= htmlentities($sValue['nickname']) ?></td>
      <td><?= $sValue['score'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $sValue['ping'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

I want to count how many players are in server(playerid) and also execute an else statement
if there are 0 players.

```
echo '<tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        </tr>';
```

Thanks you.

Comment: `server(playerid)` is not shown, did you mean `$ServerPlayers`? If so, you can use `count($ServerPlayers)` to get the length of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `index` within the `foreach loop

```
foreach( $ServerPlayers as $index => $sValue)
```

That would assign the array key to `$index` - depending upon type of array this might or might not suit your needs.

You can add your own counter to the array iteration if the source array an associative array with non integer keys.

```
$i=0;
foreach( $ServerPlayers as $svalue ){
    /* other operations */
    $i++;
}
```

You can use `count` or `sizeof` to get the number of elements in an array:

```
$size=count( $ServerPlayers );
```

If the array is empty and you wish to print some message or do some task:

```
if( empty( $ServerPlayers ) ) echo "Bad foo.. no players";
```

or, with the table idea perhaps:

```
<table>
    <?php
        
        if( empty( $ServerPlayers ) ){
            echo "
            <tr>
                <th scope='row'></th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }else{
            foreach( $ServerPlayers as $index => $svalue ){
                printf(
                    "
                    <tr>
                        <th scope='row'>%s</th>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>
                    ",
                    sValue['playerid'],
                    htmlentities($sValue['nickname']),
                    $sValue['score'],
                    $sValue['ping']
                );
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have function call count().
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use php count function to calculate the number of elements in the array.

```
$count= count($ServerPlayers);

//if array are empty then you can handle it like below:
if(empty($ServerPlayers)){

   echo "No players.";
}
```